# Change main monitor on Mac programmatically

Tags: macos, monitor

I would like to disable the primary monitor on a Mac and then change secondary monitor to be the main programmatically.
Any help on how I can do this? Not sure where to start my research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the secondary monitor to be the main screen is quite straightforward.  One need to set the origin 0,0 to the secondary display using `CGConfigureDisplayOrigin()`.

A full sample can be found [Here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/hmscreens/hmscreens.html)

To the question how to disable the monitor, unfortunately I have no answer.I am trying to figure out how it can be done because there are some applications like `SwitchResX` that are able to disable displays, so somehow it must be possible.

Answer (score 1):

hmscreens work great:

http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/hmscreens/hmscreens.html

Here's a sample command line to swap mointors:

```
hmscreens -setMainID `hmscreens -info | grep "Screen ID:" | head -2 | tail -1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`
```