# macOS CGConfigureDisplayOrigin doesn't work as expected

Tags: macos, core-graphics

I have multiple monitors and try to change the main display using Quarz Display APIs, my function is

```
int setDisplayOrigin(CGDirectDisplayID display, int x, int y) {
    CGDisplayConfigRef cfg;
    auto ret = CGBeginDisplayConfiguration(&cfg);
    if (ret != kCGErrorSuccess) return ret;
    ret = CGConfigureDisplayOrigin(cfg, display, x, y);
    if (ret != kCGErrorSuccess) return ret;
    ret = CGCompleteDisplayConfiguration(cfg, kCGConfigureForAppOnly);
    return ret;
}
```

to set specific monitor as the main one, I call this function with both 0 with x and y

```
setDisplayOrigin(directDisplayID, 0, 0)
```

macOS did rearrange the displays, but the related display won't have origin with (0, 0) when I check its bounds again, and every returned value was successful (KCGErrorSuccess)

Comment: The docs for that say "The new origin is placed as close as possible to the requested location, without overlapping or leaving a gap between displays". Since there's already a display at (0, 0), that suggests it won't be able to move the secondary display to (0, 0) unless the currently-main display is moved away, presumably in the same transaction (`CGBegin...` to `CGComplete...`). Try that. Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722508/change-main-monitor-on-mac-programmatically) and the source example the answers link to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the hint from Ken, reposition the current main display and then set the target display's origin to (0, 0) which is the way to make it work.